# How to disable noweb prefix lines?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, noweb, tangle

[This](http://orgmode.org/manual/noweb.html#noweb) says that

> Noweb insertions now honor prefix characters that appear before `<<reference>>`.

And because of that trying to use

```
#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :noweb-ref dep-cljsbuild
[lein-figwheel "0.5.9"]
[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
#+END_SRC
```

with

```
:plugins [<<dep-cljsbuild>>]
```

gives me

```
:plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.5.9"]
:plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]]
```

which is obviously not what I want. I can workaround issue by moving `<<dep-cljsbuild>>` to the new line, but it looks ugly.

Could you recommend any proper way to point org-mode that in particular place I don't want prefixes to be preserved? (Or at least how to disable it globally)

Comment: This does not appear possible to me in org. I would move the :plugins part into the noweb-ref block. The expansion is done by org-babel-expand-noweb-references.

Answer (score 1):

There is another workaround: remove newlines from the referenced code block.

According to the [Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Noweb-Reference-Syntax.html)

> Since this change does not affect noweb replacement text without newlines in them, inline noweb references are acceptable.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#+TITLE: Example

#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :noweb-ref dep-cljsbuild
[lein-figwheel "0.5.9"] [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]
#+END_SRC

#+BEGIN_SRC clojure :noweb yes
:plugins [<<dep-cljsbuild>>]
#+END_SRC
```

Previewing the second snippet when expanded using `C-c C-v v` shows:

```
:plugins [[lein-figwheel "0.5.9"] [lein-cljsbuild "1.1.5" :exclusions [[org.clojure/clojure]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :noweb yes :results verbatim
  echo \
  <<example>>
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Please consider explaining your code, to improve your answer.